# Deploying a package through puppet from URL

Tags: centos, package-management, puppet

How can i install a package through puppet by using the URL of the `.tar.gz` of the package on `centos 6` client. Is there any native support in puppet without installing anything extra on the puppet master.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to run a wget? This is an example pulling a rpm file and installing it. I also create a file in "/etc/firstruns/" so that it wont run every time. "creates" says: "Hey, I create this file when I'm done... so if it's already there, I don't need to do it!". You can also just specify the path in the command. The path parameter is not necessary. Feel free to add the deletion of the rpm too.

```
exec { 'wget':
  path      => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/", "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ],
  command   => "/bin/wget <URL> && rpm -ivh <RPM>",
  cwd       => '/tmp/',
  creates   => '/etc/firstruns/p1.done',
}
```

I can only assume I'd get smacked for not proper practices, but hey, it's an answer :D